# Is it possible to retrieve only the capture date from image or video metadata using exiftool?

Tags: date, metadata, exiftool

I am using exiftool module to fetch metadata of a video or image so I do not want entire metadata ..like I want only the capturation date as out put
I am using Linux in my machine.and I was using subprocess module which is in python to execute the command.
I am using exiftool module to fetch metadata of a video or image so I do not want entire metadata.Like I want only the capturation date as output

Comment: What exiftool module?  You don't mention the language you are using. On the command line, you would just list the the tags you want to extract.  To see all the date/time tags in a file, you would use `exiftool -time:all -G1 -a -s file.jpg`  You could then pick time stamp you want to use.

Comment: Also understand that metadata is absolute mess (see [xkcd Standards](https://xkcd.com/927/)).  There may not be a clear cut tag for the capture date and it might be different across different file types.